# IE calling jquery error handler on every img src attr update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

The below code works great in all browsers other than IE.

When stepping through the debugger, IE will replace the src with the correct image and it will appear on screen as it should but then the error function gets called and replaces it with the missing.jpg image.

Removing the error handler makes it work in all browsers including IE but when an image is missing I want to be able to show the missing.jpg image.

I've tried the caching fix but that did not work.

UPDATE:
I've added alerts to each event handler and it looks like for IE error() returned before load() can even start, but load will finish correctly, just after error.

I would like to understand what is happening and to know if there is an alternative to showing the missing.jpg image and not use the error handler.

HTML

```
<span id='imageButton' image='testing.jpg'>Click Here</span>
<img id='testImage' />
```

JS

```
$('.imageButton').bind('click', function (event) {

    var imageattr = $(this).attr('image');
    $('#testImage').attr('src', imageattr);
}

$('#cardImage').error(function () {
    $('#testImage').attr('src', 'missing.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your code.

```
$('.imageButton').bind('click', function (event) {
    var imageattr = $(this).attr('image');
    $('#testImage').attr('src', imageattr);
}) // missing )

$('#cardImage').error(function () {
    $('#testImage').attr('src', 'missing.jpg');
}) // missing )
```

Also, the `jQuery.error()` method is [depricated](https://api.jquery.com/error/), so it's to be expected that it doesn't work in some browsers.

What you could do instead is use AJAX to get the image, but if it isn't found, then revert to the missing image.

```
$('.imageButton').on('click', function fetchImage(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $img = $('#testImage'),
        src = $(this).attr('image');

    $.get({
        url: src,
        success: function(data){
            $img.attr('src', data)
        },
        dataType: 'image/jpg' // or 'image/png', 'image/gif', etc.
    }).fail(function(data){
        $img.attr('src', 'missing.jpg')
    })
})
```